# Apache AirFlow : How to schedule it on remote machines

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am new to apache airflow, Could you please help me to understand where/what should I configure to run a DAG in a remote machines.  I am using the celery_executor to execute the code on worker nodes, I have not done any configurations on worker nodes, I am using RabitMQ as queue service and seems like I have configured the Airflow cluster correctly.

My DAG file :

```
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow tutorial located at:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py
"""
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG('sample_date_print', schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *', default_args=default_args)

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep',
    bash_command='sleep 5',
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)

templated_command = """
    {% for i in range(5) %}
        echo "{{ ds }}"
        echo "{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7)}}"
        echo "{{ params.my_param }}"
    {% endfor %}
"""

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    bash_command=templated_command,
    params={'my_param': 'Parameter I passed in'},
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
t3.set_upstream(t1)
```

The logs:

```
{
  "host_name": "1f176162bc5e",
  "full_command": "['/usr/local/bin/airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'sample_date_print', 'print_date', '2015-06-04T00:00:00+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/root/airflow/dags/sample_date_print.py']"
}
```

I am not sure how should I change the default behavior of `--local`   in a way that DAG file 
go and execute on remote machines, please help me

Comment: Have you gotten this to work yet? If so, please post the solution here so I can solve mine too :)
I am currently running airflow on a virtual machine and another celery worker on my local machine, but the main application in the virtual machine/local celery worker do not detect my local DAGs... I assume this is part of your problem too? :P

Answer (score -1):

Have you changed the `executor = SequentialExecutor` to `executor = CeleryExecutor` in your `airflow.cfg`? I think you have not or if you have you forgot to mention it.
It's the firs thing to change if you want to change execution mode.
Other things you might've missed with configurations could be mentioned [here](http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/setting-apache-airflow-cluster/) or [here](https://medium.com/@khatri_chetan/how-to-setup-airflow-multi-node-cluster-with-celery-rabbitmq-cfde7756bb6a).

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it, and it is mentioned in the question description ;)